# Firestore operations with cloud functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am developing mobile app with flutter framework in which I am using Firestore database and Firebase cloud functions. I have successfully implemented both in my project. However, I have some difficulties understanding how to run functions that are independent from my app. For example, if I have a Firestore database of 100 people and want to calculate average user age for my own analysis. I know that I can call the function calculateAverageAge() from my app, however is there a way to call this function without adding it in my app's code? Should I create a separate project (possibly in different language) and call those functions from there or I can somehow trigger this function from firebase website? Not sure what is the the right approach here.

Hopefully that makes sense.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general there are three common ways to trigger a function:

- Explicitly call it from your client-side application code, which applies to either [HTTP functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) or [Callable functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable).
- Run them periodically on a [schedule](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions).
- Run them when something in the data (or in another Firebase feature, or EventArc for v2) changes with [background functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events).

For your example of calculating the average age of your users, this means that you could combine the last two types and:

- Recalculate the average whenever a new user gets added to the database, or a user gets removed from the database.
- And then also run a scheduled function daily to update the average for any birthdays.